# ShowToastEvent mode:pester

Tags: lightning-web-components

Using toasts in LWC to display notifications to user.    mode: 'pester' does not appear to work, the toast still disappears after 3 seconds.

DOC:
pester: Remains visible until the close button is clicked.

```
 handleWarning() {
const showWarning = new ShowToastEvent({
    title: 'Warning!',
    mode: 'pester',
    message: 'This is Warning message',
    variant: 'warning'
});
this.dispatchEvent(showWarning);  }
```

Other modes work fine (dismissable, sticky).

Answer (score 3):

Caching issue.  It is working as expected.