# pester mode not working for showToastEvent in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-quickaction, toast

I have a Lightning web component (LWC) using showToastEvent.  The `pester` mode is not working right -- I do not see a close icon and it closes automatically in 3 seconds.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251406/showtoastevent-modepester) says to clear the cache, but I've tried it on separate browsers and machines and it still doesn't work properly.

The close icon is displayed for `dismissable` but I want to use `pester`.

Has anyone else seen this issue?  I'm using the LWC in a quick action so I've had to wrap it an aura component.  Could this be the reason?

```
const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
    "title": "Warning",
    "message": "You must enter at least a zip code, an email or a mobile number",
    "mode": "pester",
    "variant": "warning"
});
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay looks like [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) is a bit messed. This is what I found by trying all

1. **pester** - Stays for 3 seconds, No close symbol
2. **sticky** - Stays infinitely or Until you press the close button
3. **dismissable** - Stays for 3 seconds, you can close it by pressing close button.